# how to groupby and count on every column in r

Tags: r

I have a following dataframe in r

```
   Introvert     Extrovert    Biased     Village.Name
    Positive      Negative    Negative     ABC
    Negative      Negative    Negative     ABC
    Negative      Positive    Positive     ABC
    Positive      Negative    Negative     DEF
    Negative      Positive    Positive     DEF
    Negative      Positive    Positive     DEF
```

I want to count `Positive` in every columns grouped by `Village.Name`

My desired dataframe would be

```
    Village.Name     Introvert    Extrovert    Biased
     ABC                1            1           1
     DEF                1            2           2
```

How can I do it in R?

Comment: `aggregate(.~Village.Name, df, function(x) sum(x=="Positive"))` in base R.

Comment: `setDT(df)[,lapply(.SD,function(x)sum(x=="Positive")),by="Village.Name"]` in `data.table`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use a group by `summarise_all` to get the `sum` of logical vector (`.== "Positive"`) for each of the columns

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
    group_by(Village.Name) %>%
    summarise_all(funs(sum(.=="Positive")))
# A tibble: 2 x 4
#  Village.Name Introvert Extrovert Biased
#  <chr>            <int>     <int>  <int>
#1 ABC                  1         1      1
#2 DEF                  1         2      2
```